# Will setting <supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"> hide the App in the Android Market for such devices?

Tags: android, manifest

I am asking because i can install the app on a device with a small screen via the file system.
Thanks for Help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[“Supporting Multiple Screens”](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) is pretty clear about this:

> Assume that you declare `smallScreens="false" normalScreens="false" largeScreens="true" xlargeScreens="true"` in your application's manifest.
>   Android Market filters the application from users of devices with *small* and *normal* size screens. In effect, this prevents such users from installing the application.

If the device is larger than the app supports, compatibility features are applied. If the device is smaller than the app supports, it is hidden from the Market.

Answer (score 1):

Those settings determine what devices see what apps in the market. So yes if you do smallScreens=false, devices which are considered to have small screens will not see the app in the market.

Comment: read below the compatibility section. if installed it will run it in compatibility mode, but the market does filter it out.